# PHP Parse error: syntax error,

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, syntax

I keep getting the following error when building an array:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
```

for the following code:

```
$fetchResult=$PubMedClient->run_eFetch(array(
'db'=>'pubmed',
'id'=>(count($searchResult->IdList->Id)>1 ? join(",",$searchResult->IdList->Id) : $searchResult->IdList->Id)));
```

I've tried to break this up in many ways, but it does not work. As usual, I'm sure it is something simple that I'm just not seeing.

Anyone have an idea?

Many thanks

Comment: Put another `)` before `;` at the end of your code?

Comment: Another closing ) is required at the end. You've not closed your run_eFetch function

Comment: Do you want _us_ to count your brackets? Use a decent IDE or count them yourself.

Comment: Try to learn how to decipher the error messages :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be slightly easier to read if you broke out the ternary operation into a variable like so:

```
$getID = count($searchResult->IdList->Id) > 1 ? join(",", $searchResult->IdList->Id) : $searchResult->IdList->Id;

$fetchResult = $PubMedClient->run_eFetch(
    array(
        'db'=>'pubmed',
        'id'=> $getID
    )
);
```

The above should work.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses. I did close with the last bracket ")" before the semicolon, but that was not working either.